# how to make a slow effect for Drop down menu for websites

Tags: drop-down-menu, dreamweaver, menubar

im using dreamweaver to make a website. im wondering how to make a drop down menu similar to the ones in http://www.evga.com/.

Comment: If u are bothered about SEO(/traffic) dont use JavaScript menus

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the source for the page shows that it is using a JavaScript based menu system that works within DL/DT/DD "lists". The JavaScript appears to require specifically classed elements to work and uses the following file: http://www.evga.com/includes/js/dropdown.js

That file doesn't have any licensing information, but a very quick search and I ran across the following page that gives some instructions for it's use: http://www.cloft.co.uk/menu%20scripts.html

As I haven't tried to use those instructions, perhaps they can assist you.